# Does knowing the totient of a number help factoring it?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, totient-function

**Edit:** The quoted question addresses only numbers of the form $p^a q^b$, I asked a general question for arbitrary $n$.

---

If $n$ is a prime or a product of 2 primes then knowing its totient $\varphi(n)$ allows us immediately to find the prime factorization of $n$.

How about a general case? Does knowing $\varphi(n)$

1. give us a way how to find the prime factorization of $n$,
2. help as find a *prime* factor of $n$, or at least
3. help at in finding *any* factor of $n$? <sup>(This turns out to be obvious.)</sup>

Comment: If $n$ is not square-free, then $gcd(n, \phi(n))$ is a non-trivial factor.

Comment: @RossMillikan The question you link deals with the case when $n=p^a q^b$. So it truly gives a partial answer to this one, but not to the general case when $n$ has 3 or more prime factors.

Comment: If http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture is true, there are at least two numbers having same totient value.

Answer (score 18):

In fact, it is a well-known observation in cryptography that just knowing a positive multiple of $\phi(n)$ helps greatly in factoring $n$, regardless of the number of prime factors (if there's only one or two primes dividing $n$ then this has already been covered).

Suppose $m$ is a multiple of $\phi(n)$.  Then if you factor out enough powers of $2$ from $m$, there must exist a divisor $t = m/(2^r)$ such that $\lambda(n) \mid 2t$ but $\lambda(n) \nmid t$.  (Here, $\lambda(n)$ is the Carmichael function, which will necessarily be even, unless $n$ is trivially small.)

It will then be the case that for some bases $b$, $b$ will be a quadratic residue for some prime $p \mid n$ but not for a different $q \mid n$.  In this case, taking the GCD $(b^t-1,n)$ will produce a non-trivial factor of $n$.

One simply has to randomly try different values of $b$ (the expected number of tries is finite), as well as different choices of $t$ (there are at most $\log(n)$ possibilities, and one can use successive squaring to efficiently cover them).

To get all the prime factors of $n$, just keep repeating the process (we still have a multiple of $\phi$ for each of factors found above).

Just to clarify: this works no matter how large the gap between $\phi(n)$ and $m$ is; the only restriction is that $m$ isn't so ridiculously large (e.g. being $O(n^c)$ digits long) that just doing any kind of arithmetic on $m$ is slower than factoring $n$.  That's why this doesn't imply a general factoring algorithm: while something like $n!$ is definitely a multiple of $\phi(n)$, it is far too big to use here.

Comment: Why the downvote?  This is the only actual answer to the question.

Comment: This answer doesn't explain how to compute the Carmichael function

Comment: @BoltonBailey If you read the answer, it doesn't actually need to compute the Carmichael function.  The fact that $t$ exists is all you need to run the computation, because the number of choices of $t$ is very small, you can try each of them and one of them is "guaranteed" to work (bearing in mind there is some non-determinism in the algorithm).

Comment: I see, I guess I just got stuck on the second paragraph, thinking the divisibility propositions there were a part of the computation, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: A second question: by "base" I presume you mean "a number in Z/nZ", and you say "the expected number of tries is finite" can we prove that the expected number of tries is actually polynomial in the size of the inputs?

Comment: @BoltonBailey Good question, yes actually I should have said the expected number of tries is *bounded*, which is even better than polynomial.  I think it in the worst case that there are only two prime factors $p,q$ then the expected number of trials is $4$, and if there are more primes, then it should be smaller as there are more pathways to success.

Comment: @BoltonBailey And yes, I use base as a standard term of art as this process is very similar to Fermat primality testing (and Miller-Rabin which is an especially close relative to the idea in this post).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of a prime, you can just observe that $\phi(n)=n-1$ to know it is prime.  If $n=pq$ is a product to two primes, $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$, which you still need to factor.  If you already know it is the product of two primes, you can use $\phi(n)=n-p-q+1$ to get $p+q$ as a second equation.  As $\phi(n)$ has at least a couple factors of $2$ and may have other small factors, it will be somewhat smaller and can be easy to factor.  Hagen von Eitzen makes a good point in the comment.  If $n=pqr$, all prime, $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)(r-1)$ and I don't see a good way to make headway except looking for small factors.

Comment: I'm assuming OP meant you know $n$ and $\phi(n)$. If you know $pq$ and $(p-1)(q-1)$, you can find $p+q$ and hence find $p$ and $q$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  that was the point of my saying "if you already know it is a product of two primes".  If you don't know that, it doesn't help.  I added a few words.

Comment: @RossMillikan If we don't know that $n=pq$ we can still proceed the same way to compute $p$ and $q$. If the computation succeeds and $pq=n$ then we have the result, otherwise we at least know that $n$ has more prime factors than 2.

Comment: Does it help that the prime factors of $p-1,q-1,r-1$ are all likely to be orders of magnitude smaller than $p$, $q$, and $r$? If you then invest in factoring $\phi(n)$, then you have a finite number of combinations of those factors to check to see if they correspond to a factorization $pqr$. Maybe this is not efficient. I wonder what the statistics are on the size of primes dividing $\phi(n)$ versus of those dividing $n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $p^e$ divides $n$ then $p^{e-1}$ divides $\phi(n)$.